# How to parse year-week to date in Python?

Tags: python

I'm converting dates in Python to year-week format using %Y-%W format. I was expecting to be able to convert from year-week to back to date, using the same string, but instead I get 1st of January (Python 3.9.1).

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strftime(datetime(2020,6,22), '%Y-%W')
# This returns 2020-25 
datetime.strptime('2020-25', '%Y-%W')
# This returns datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Why is that and what's the best way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the answer in the documentation footnote when I continued searching.

> When used with the strptime() method, %U and %W are only used in
> calculations when the day of the week and the calendar year (%Y) are
> specified.

https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Would have expected it to raise an error or return the date corresponding to Monday, as the documentation specifies that with %W the week starts on Monday.

So to fix this we need to include the weekday in the string and in the format.

```
datetime.strptime('2020-25-1', '%Y-%W-%w')
# returns datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 0, 0)
```